# Only first submit to Firebase, doesnt work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

i created these inputs, from which i want my data to be stored in firebase.

Problem is, that every FIRST ONLY submit, doesnt work, every submit after, works just fine.

Can someone help me find out where the problem is?

```
export default function TransactionScreen() {
  const [account, setAccount] = useState("");
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState("");

  const handleTransaction = async e => {
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`Transaction`)
      .add({
        account,
        amount,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        deletedAt: null,
        updatedAt: null
      });
  };
  return (
    <Card width bold>
      New Transaction
      <form onSubmit={handleTransaction} className="Transaction-form">
        <div className="Transaction-form__input">
          Transfer to:
          <Input
            width
            placeholder="Transfer to"
            onChange={setAccount}
            value={account}
            type="number"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="Transaction-form__input">
          Amount:
          <Input
            width
            placeholder="Amount"
            onChange={setAmount}
            value={amount}
            type="number"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="Transaction-form__btn">
          <Button bordered>Send Transaction</Button>
        </div>
      </form>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im answering my own question!

I found out where the problem was,

i didnt use e.prevenDefault(); after

const handleTransaction = async e => {

so the correct way is :

`const handleTransaction = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    await firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection(`Transaction`)
      .add({
        account,
        amount,
        createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
        deletedAt: null,
        updatedAt: null
      })
      .then(setAccount(""), setAmount(""));
  };`